# HTML extends larger than screen size

Tags: html, css

i have finished the HTML structure for the new lay-out of our website for the scuba diving club. A designer made the lay-out and i put it together in html.

Everything fits nicely, except there is a problem with the height and width. I have refactored it but doesn't see how to solve it. The top banner and left image, navigation has a fixed width. the content text div should take up the rest of the space and the scrollbars needs to be in the div. Only the content need to be scrolled, not the whole page. The first problem is the very large width and height.

The scrollbars are hidden, but you can test it here: http://test.profunda.be/newlayoutr2.html
and the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/u9buvpL0/3/

I think it has something to do with:

```
    .div-main-right-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    word-break: normal;
    background-color: white;
    left: 220px;

}
```

and the fact that the containing div has full width and height.

Comment: try adding <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> in the head of your html

Comment: First thing; .div-main-right-content float:left; won't work, because you position element absolutly.
Second; because you position this element absolutly it gonna have 100% size of its container. It's not good idea to build table-based site. 

Most of your site should have one background to fit and scale properly. Only .div-main-left-menu can have seperated bg and should be much easier to position it absolutly (only this element! :) ).
Also on your site we can see white space at the bottom. It's because .div-main-left-menu top value among others. 
Floating element are much easier to build :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no sense to use float: right together with position: absolute.

Then, you gave 100% to your right content div and it takes 100% of its container width. And of course goes outside because left column already took a part of width.
You can use this to make right column take all free width:
Add additional div main-right-inner.
Use this css:

```
.div-main-right
{

    margin-left: 330px;
}

.main-right-inner {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Additionally in div-main-right-content delete 
`float: right;
position: absolute;`

Edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u9buvpL0/6/

The additional wrapper .main-right-inner is to avoid possible problems with clearing floated elements inside right column.

Comment: I have worked oon the site and updated. https://jsfiddle.net/u9buvpL0/7/ To test live: http://test.profunda.be/newlayoutr3.html. Now I just need the height to be fixed.

Comment: This answer is used for the width. For the height  i used javascript, since i want that the height of the div fills the screen, even on resize. `<script>
            function myFunction()
            {
                var h = window.innerHeight;
                //document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML = "Width: " + w + "<br>Height: " + h;
                document.getElementById("cont").style.height = (h - 134)+"px";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body onresize="myFunction()" onload="myFunction()">` I know it not the best way but it is resolved.

Comment: You can use css `calc`: `.cont { height: calc(100vh - 134px);}`. It is widely supported nowadays: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc . And if you care about outdated browsers, you can use modernizr to check browser support and use your above jquery function as fallback.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in div-main div you have two columns, one with fixed width and one with percent width. This cause your layout width "strange". You can quick-fix it with resizing your divs with fixed widths.

The vertical scroll problem is caused by `overflow-y: scroll;` in body: cancel it and it works.

I have seen too much `position:absolute` in your code... is dangerous, use it with care. Use relative positioning, more difficult but more useful.

Answer (score 0):

i saw your code, use to

```
.div-main{width:59%}
```

to align proper

Answer (score 0):

```
user this code 
.div-main-right-content
{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    word-break: normal;
    background-color: white;
    left: 220px;
}
```